# sysRestart Billion ADSL router (SNMP v2 or HTTP)

Tags: snmp, oid, reset

**Background**

I am used to restart my servers on a scheduled basis. Now I want the same for my ADSL router.

This is my reason: When a random failure occurs, I am used to normally try to reboot the servers , interfaces and related equipments (if possible) as the first step before any other troubleshooting (e.g: changing configurations, etc). 
In fact there are times that this corrects the problem (The service starts working as expected). This may be because when a system is long time up (sometimes, depending on the software and services), it may become unresponsive or faulty. May be the software fails to release some memory, unlock some resources , etc

Now for some services which scheduled down time is acceptable during non-work hours, I schedule the automatic restart. This way, such type of problems appear less frequently. And now if a problem occurs during work-hours, I don't need to restart the whole service, instead I will resume troubleshooting like after I had restarted them.

**What we have**

This is a Billion 5000 Series router and supports TELNET, HTTP and SNMP for management.

**Telnet method (Updated)**

This is possible to reboot the router via telnet command:

```
C:\>telnet 192.168.1.1
    Password:********
    router>set reboot
```

So near, just need a script that automatically telnets, pushes password characters and issues the '*set reboot*' command. [The approach of using *expect* suggested by *SvenW*]

**HTTP method**

Good to mention that I utilize a *software*[**1**] application for monitoring my ADSL connection speed and noise margin via HTTP interface (the software itself, instead of a browser application, connects, logs in unattendedly and reads the values from HTTP interface and display them in a graph!).

I wonder if it is possible to achieve the SysRestart with similar approach (A script that automatically logs in and clicks the SysRestart button!)

The restart page:

- Picture of the page: 
  [image: HTML Page with restart button]
- The source HTML of the page:

  ```
  <html><head>
  <meta http-equiv=Content-Script-Type content=text/javascript>
  <meta http-equiv=Content-Style-Type content=text/css>
  <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=
  iso-8859-1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <script language="JavaScript"> 
  function doRefresh()
  {
      alert("Reboot Complete");   parent.navigation.location.href = "/navigation-status.html";
      window.location.href = "../status/status_deviceinfo.htm";
  }

  function doLoad()
  {

       }

  </script>
  </head><body onload="doLoad()">
  <FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="/Forms/tools_system_1" name="System_Restore">
  <table width="760" border="0" align=center cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <td height="5" class="light-orange" colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
      <td width="150" height="30" class="title-main">
      <font color="#FFFFFF">System Restart</font>    </td><td width="10" class="black">&nbsp;</td><td width="150"></td><td width="10"> </td><td width="440"></td></tr><tr>
      <td class="light-orange">&nbsp;</td><td class="light-orange"></td><td class="tabdata"><div align=right>
      <font color="#000000">System Restart with</font>    </div></td><td class="tabdata"><div align=center>:</div></td><td class="tabdata">
          <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="restoreFlag" VALUE="0" CHECKED>       <font color="#000000">Current Settings</font>       </td></tr><tr>
      <td class="light-orange">&nbsp;</td><td class="light-orange"></td><td class="tabdata">&nbsp;</td><td class="tabdata">&nbsp;</td><td class="tabdata">
          <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="restoreFlag" VALUE="1">       <font color="#000000">Factory Default Settings</font>       </td></tr><tr>
      <td class="light-orange">&nbsp;</td><td class="light-orange"></td><td width="150">&nbsp;</td><td width="10">&nbsp;</td><td width="440">&nbsp;</td></tr></table><table width="760" border="0" align=center cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
      <td width="160" class="black" height="42" >&nbsp;</td><td width="160" class="orange">&nbsp;</td><td width="440" class="orange">
          <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Restart" VALUE="RESTART">    </td></tr></table></div></form>
  </body></html>
  ```

**SNMP Method**

The router also has support for SNMP v2 read and write communities. I thought it might be possible to perform it this way.

In fact, by some search I *found*[**2**] that some people use SNMP to restart their devices (But I can't find an OID for my router to pass for performing a reset)

For example it appear that those who have one of these devices can reboot them using these OIDs:

```
'.1.3.6.1.4.1.207.8.4.4.3.2.0',    # Allied Telesyn restart
'.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.1.4.1.0', # Hewlett-Packard hpicfReset
'.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.5.1.1.9.0',        # Cisco CatOS sysReset
'.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.9.9.0',          # Cisco IOS tsMsgSend
'.1.3.6.1.4.1.529.9.8.0.0'         # Ascend sysReset
```

**SNMP Walk**

Using SNMP walk I could get a list of more than five hundred OIDs such as:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16972.5.1.1.0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16972.4.10.0
...etc (568 more)...
```

But I have currently no idea how can I pick one among them (specially afraid to test snmp-write on them!).

**Some more info**

Some other (walked) OID and values that might help:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16972.1.3.0; Trendchip TC3162 T14F7_3.0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16972.5.1.1.0; www.huawei.com
.1.3.6.1.4.1.16972.1.6.0; Ras Ver:2.10.4.0(UE0.C2C)3.6.0.0   DMT Ver:3.6.0.0
```

**How can you help ?**

- Suggesting a way to script a restart via SNMP (Requires finding the
  OID first!?)
- Suggesting a way to script a restart via HTTP
- Suggesting a way to script a restart via telnet
- Suggesting a way to script a restart (any other ways!)

**FootNotes:**

- [**1**] http://vwlowen.co.uk/internet/files.htm
- [**2**] http://www.skendric.com/nmgmt/device/Generic/reset-device

Comment: Provide source code of web page where you see the restart button, so that anyone could help you with the script.

Comment: @John: Image and source code of webpage added to the question text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a proper MIB file for SNMP your best bet will to either find some telnet command that does the restart and maybe use it with the help of the `expect` tool or to use something like `curl` to use the web interface.

Using curl might require multiple calls to it to first login and save a session cookies and then to do the actual restart.

I do wonder though - do you have an actual problem with the device you try to fix with a regular restart? If not, I can't see the reason to do so.

Edit:

Basic example for an expect script. Call it with `scriptname hostname password` or alter the variable assignments to contain the actual hostname and password:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

set timeout 15
set hostname [lindex $argv 0] 
set password [lindex $argv 1] 

spawn telnet $hostname 

expect "Password:" 
send "$password " 
expect "router>" 
send "set reboot "
```

Comment: The telnet section updated with showing the command to execute the reboot. Also the background section updated to show the reason behind doing this scheduled reboot.

Comment: @AliFakoor: See my edit for an `expect` example. More infos via `man expect` and Google.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. 

I should have mentioned that it is a windows host connected to router, but thats fine, I will go do the rest (finding / compiling expect port for windows, etc). Tnx a lot